# Parallel insert in db2

Tags: db2, insert, parallelism, bulk-insert, scripting

I am trying to import from 8 files and insert into a single table in db2. I am running 8 .sql files that will do the task, but only one of them actually seem to be running and inserting into table.

Is there a way, I can make 8 inserts happen in parallel into the same table so that it completes faster ?

Comment: Staying at the same level of detail, yes, there are ways to do that.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I am not clear what you mean.

Comment: It is not practical to give a detailed advice without knowing anything about your environment and process. What is your DB2 version? Platform? Server hardware? What are the 8 files? How big are they? How are you running your scripts? What is in those scripts? Please also keep in mind that running 8 things in parallel is not always faster than running them sequentially.